# How do I redirect a particular querystring with wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to redirect all links like https://domain.com/?p=download&a=111146&b=98b307bc6f1fe4b9682b2740980c4afb to domain.com/some/page

The "p=download" is always constant. I have tried the following without any luck:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=download$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://domain.com/customer-service/downloads-moved/  [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone point out what we I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. There is no rule for your type of request. You have only rule, for `https://domain.com/?p=download`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect user on download page to another download page, your `.htaccess` is right now.

But if you want to redirect to this other page with params, add a new condition after your current condition.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=download(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)  https://domain.com/some/page/$1  [R=301,L]
```

This

```
https://domain.com/?p=download&a=111146&b=98b307bc6f1fe4b9682b2740980c4afb
```

will be redirect you to

```
http://www.domain.com/some/page/?p=download&a=111146&b=98b307bc6f1fe4b9682b2740980c4afb
```

Your current code is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=download$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://domain.com/customer-service/downloads-moved/  [R=301,L]
```

what will redirect

```
https://domain.com/?p=download
```

to

```
https://domain.com/customer-service/downloads-moved/
```

**UPDATE**

Based on OP comment:

Ok, the problem is that you wrote this: `^p=download$` It mens it should be matched exactly the `p=download` string, because of your `^` and `$`.

So if you want to redirect all the requests, what contains `p=download` at the start of the `QUERY_STRING`, then combine my two suggestion:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=download(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)  https://domain.com/customer-service/downloads-moved/  [R=301,L]
```

It means everythin what is started with this string `^p=download` (and there could be nothing or anything after this string) will be redirected to that url what you gave in `RewirteRule`

Comment: I want all links with ?p=download to redirect to that one page. I don't need to append the querystring.
If my code is right, then the redirect should happen but it is not.